# Autounattend.xml does not match custom install.wim

Tags: windows, automated-install, xml, dism, wim

Here is my procedure for better understanding:

1. Conducted Windows 10 IoT installation in Audit Mode.
2. Added German language and performed updates.
3. Shut down the PC in Sysprep/Generalize and restarted with a Windows ISO.
4. Opened Command Prompt and created the install.wim file.
5. Copied install.wim to my main computer.
6. Used AnyBurn to replace the install.wim file and placed my autounattend.xml in the root directory.
7. Mounted the ISO on the Hyper-V Server and performed the installation.

So far, everything has worked.

The issue now is that  Windows Setup displays the message "No images are available." I understand this since I no longer have the original install.wim but a customized version specified as `D:\ISO\sources\install.wim`. However, the installation works flawlessly without the XML file.

My question is: How do I combine my customized install.wim file with my automated installation? Do I need to modify my XML file, or is this approach no longer possible once I've created a custom install.wim?

Capture Image command

```
dism /capture-image /imagefile:C:\Image\install.wim /capturedir:C:\ /ScratchDir:C:\Scratch /name:"Windows 10 IoT Enterprise LTSC" /description:"Windows 10 IoT Enterprise LTSC" /compress:maximum /checkintegrity /verify
```

Autounattend.xml File

```
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>0409:00000409</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
            <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DiskConfiguration>
                <Disk wcm:action="add">
                    <CreatePartitions>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <Size>300</Size>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>4</Order>
                            <Extend>true</Extend>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>3</Order>
                            <Size>128</Size>
                            <Type>MSR</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Size>100</Size>
                            <Type>EFI</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                    </CreatePartitions>
                    <ModifyPartitions>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                            <TypeID>DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC</TypeID>
                            <Label>WINRE</Label>
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>4</Order>
                            <PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <Label>OS</Label>
                            <Letter>C</Letter>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                            <Label>System</Label>
                            <Format>FAT32</Format>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <PartitionID>3</PartitionID>
                            <Order>3</Order>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                    </ModifyPartitions>
                    <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                    <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
                </Disk>
            </DiskConfiguration>
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <InstallFrom>
                        <MetaData wcm:action="add">
                            <Value>Windows 10 IoT Enterprise LTSC</Value>
                            <Key>/Image/Description</Key>
                        </MetaData>
                        <Path>D:\ISO\sources\install.wim</Path>
                    </InstallFrom>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                        <PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
                    </InstallTo>
                </OSImage>
            </ImageInstall>
            <UserData>
                <ProductKey>
                    <Key>M7XTQ-FN8P6-TTKYV-9D4CC-J462D</Key>
                    <WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
                </ProductKey>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
            </UserData>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Password>
                    <Value>MQAyADMAMQAzADEAMwAzADQANABQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQA</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <LogonCount>9999999</LogonCount>
                <Username>User</Username>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            </AutoLogon>
            <RegisteredOwner>User</RegisteredOwner>
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
                <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <NetworkLocation>Home</NetworkLocation>
                <SkipMachineOOBE>true</SkipMachineOOBE>
                <SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>
                <ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>
            </OOBE>
            <UserAccounts>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value>MQAyADMAMQAzADEAMwAzADQANABQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQA</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <DisplayName>User</DisplayName>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <Name>User</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>false</DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>
            <TimeZone>W. Europe Standard Time</TimeZone>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>0407:00000407</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>de-DE</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>de-DE</UILanguage>
            <UILanguageFallback>de-DE</UILanguageFallback>
            <UserLocale>de-DE</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipAutoActivation>true</SkipAutoActivation>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-SQMApi" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <CEIPEnabled>0</CEIPEnabled>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <RegisteredOwner />
            <ComputerName>SN-2023</ComputerName>
            <ProductKey>M7XTQ-FN8P6-TTKYV-9D4CC-J462D</ProductKey>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="offlineServicing">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-LUA-Settings" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <EnableLUA>false</EnableLUA>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="generalize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="NonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipRearm>1</SkipRearm>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:d:/iso/sources/install.wim#Windows 10 IoT Enterprise LTSC" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

After playing around and trying things out a bit, I received another error message:

"Windows could not collect information for [OSImage] since the specified image file `[D:\ISO\sources\install.wim]` does not exist.".
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12jfZ.png)

I also tried changing the storage location and changing it to D: without ISO. Or on a NAS but unfortunately that didn't help.

Without the Custom ISO with my own XML it worked right away.

Comment: `I also tried changing the storage location and changing it to D` this usually means that D: is assigned to another location (the setup media) and the drive you need may be another letter such as E.